# Multiple web-api Methods name start with 'Delete' showing 500 internal server error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using Asp.net mvc4 web-api.

I have 2 web-api methods both with starting keyword "Delete" and throwing 500 internal server error.

//working fine

```
public HttpResponseMessage DeleteMenu(MenuModel objMenuModel)
{

}
```

not working - showing 500 internal server error

```
public HttpResponseMessage DeleteAllMenu(MenuModel objMenuModel)
{

}
```

DeleteAllMenu method not working as it is already DeleteMenu method. If I comment DeleteMenu related stuff then DeleteAllMenu is working other wise throwing 500 internal server error.

Comment: Please do not forget to add in {action} attribute in WebApiConfig.cs file with routes..That the solution