# Delete method with array type as parameter showing null value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, null, asp.net-web-api

I am calling web-api method delete all with array type parameter, showing the value `null`. why?

I am passing data like : data: "ArrMenuId"+ JsArrayMenuId,

```
function performalldeletemenu()
{

    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this menu?'))
    {
        var JsArrayMenuId = new Array();
        $("input:checked").each(function ()
        {
            //console.log($(this).val()); //works fine
            JsArrayMenuId.push($(this).val());
        });
        alert(JsArrayMenuId);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/MenuWebApi/DeleteAllMenu/',
            type: 'DELETE',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: "ArrMenuId"+ JsArrayMenuId,
            success: function (data)
            {
                if (data.Success == true)
                {
                    //GetMenuList();
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                //window.location = JsErrorAction;
            },

            headers:
            {
                'RequestVerificationToken': JsTokenHeaderValue
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}



public HttpResponseMessage DeleteAllMenu(Array ArrMenuId)
{

}
```

Here ArrMenuId is showing null values.

if any one have solution, please let me know.

Comment: What does your delete method look like in your web api ? please add that to your question.

You must be passing data in the wrong way, its very picky.. look here on how to pass data - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I am passing data like : data: "ArrMenuId"+ JsArrayMenuId, I have added method name + jquery ajax function call in my question.

Comment: I have also checked using this : data: {ArrMenuId : JsArrayMenuId}, but same issue. please help me on it

Comment: I am not sure you can pass an array like that from javascript to your controller.

Try changing your controller method to DeleteAllMenu(string ArrMenuId) and doing 

data: {ArrMenuId : JsArrayMenuId.join()} in your javascript

Comment: Hi if i am doing your way it is showing 404 error. DeleteAllMenu(string ArrMenuId) -> DeleteAllMenu(MenuModel ArrMenuId) if i am passing model then it is working and also your suggestion .join{} is good ...Thanks for your help MR krilovich .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
data: "ArrMenuId"+ JsArrayMenuId,
```

to

```
data: {ArrMenuId : JsArrayMenuId.join()}
```

and changing

```
public HttpResponseMessage DeleteAllMenu(Array ArrMenuId)
```

to

```
public HttpResponseMessage DeleteAllMenu(string ArrMenuId)
```

I don't think javascript array will translate easily into a c# array and by changing it to this you are instead passing a string. Once you have this comma delimited string you can make it into an array in your c#

Comment: All is correct with your suggestion, just need to pass model with controller, string type showing 404 error.

Comment: Hi, I have another issue if you have any idea. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18213485/asp-net-mvc4-web-api-methods2-methods-name-start-with-delete-showing-500-in